# Popen.stdout.readline() works in Python 3.2 but returns empty string in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-3.2

I am using Popen to start a telnet process over ssh, send commands through the telnet and check the process for output to monitor the state of the telnet. The weird thing I encountered is that the code works fine with Python 3.2.3 but when I run it in Python 3.6.5 with no code changes, it fails to get the output.

I have tried

- flushing the stdout
- waiting up to 10s after stdout.write
- checked stderr

```py
def nonblockingread(sout):
   fd = output.fileno()
   fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
   try:
       return sout.read()
   except:
       return ""

process = Popen(shlex.split("ssh anon@server \"telnet 0 2323\""), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(nonblockingread(process.stdout)) # works for both versions
process.stdin.write(b"start service 4\n")
print(nonblockingread(process.stdout)) # works in 3.2 but not 3.6 (prints empty line)
print(process.stdout.readline()) # also prints empty line in 3.6
```

Comment: Why are you writing to the readable process.stdout rather than the writable process.stdin?

Comment: That was a typo

Comment: There seems to be some code missing—you never set anything non-blocking, for instance.  Is your “service 4” actually started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffering was turned on by default in [3.2.4 and 3.3.1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), having been turned off inadvertently in Python 3.  You need to `flush` your **`write`** to `process.stdin` for the other side to see anything.